# Autofilling from one array to another

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, xcode4.5

Is there a similar pattern in objective-c to create an observer pattern as there is in Java? 
That way the attributes of a super class will pass inheritance to subclasses.

Comment: Sure, there is KVO that you can use. But I can't help you any further as the question is unclear to me. Could you give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to make an observer like pattern in objective-c much like can be done in Java. The pattern creates a superclass and then generic items are inherited to the subclass. For example. there would be a super class of ducks, and the sub classes would inherit traits like can fly, has feathers, the duckness would be passed from parent to child.